# Solve this system of equations for acceleration

Tags: calculus, physics

[image]

I'm dealing with a double Atwood's machine problem, and so far I got these $F=ma$ equations:

$T - m_2g = m_2 a_2$

$T - m_3g = m_3 a_3$

$2T - m_1g = m_1 a_1$

$a_1 = -\frac{(a_2 + a_3)}{2}$ (relating acceleration of mass 1 to the others).

However, now I somehow have to solve for $a_1, a_2$ and $a_3$, and get the following results:

\begin{align*} a_1 = g \frac{4m_2 m_3 - m_1(m_2 + m_3)}{4m_2 m_3 + m_1 (m_2 + m_3)} \\ a_2 = -g \frac{4m_2 m_3 + m_1 (m_2 - 3m_3)}{4m_2 m_3 + m_1 (m_2 + m_3)} \end{align*} and \begin{align*} a_3 = -g \frac{4m_2 m_3 + m_1 (m_3 - 3m_2)}{4m_2 m_3 + m_1 (m_2 + m_3)}. \end{align*}

I've tried adding, substracting, substituting forever...nothing seems to work. Can someone explain me how one derives these equations? Would mean a lot! Please don't delete/move this post, since this is a 'mathematical' problem (I've done the physics part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have four equations
$$T - m_2g = m_2 a_2 \text{ (1)}$$
$$T - m_3g = m_3 a_3 \text{ (2)}$$
$$2T - m_1g = m_1 a_1 \text{ (3)}$$
$$a_1 = -\frac{(a_2 + a_3)}{2}\text{ (4)}$$
Add $m_3\times(1)$ to $m_2\times(2)$ to obtain
$$\begin{align} T(m_2+m_3)-2m_2m_3g&=m_2m_3(a_2+a_3)
\\\Rightarrow T(m_2+m_3)-2m_2m_3g&=-2(m_2m_3)a_1
\\\Rightarrow 2T(m_2+m_3)-4m_2m_3g&=-4m_2m_3a_1\\\Rightarrow (m_1g+m_1a_1)(m_2+m_3)-4m_2m_3g&=-4m_2m_3a_1\\\Rightarrow a_1=g\frac{4m_2m_3-m_1(m_2+m_3)}{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2+m_3)} \end{align}$$
Having found $a_1$, using equation $(3)$ we can express $T$ as
$$T=\frac{m_1(a_1+g)}{2}\Rightarrow T=g\frac{4m_2m_3}{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2+m_3)}$$
and substitute $T$ into equation $(1)$ to find $a_2$ as follows:-
$$g\frac{4m_2m_3}{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2+m_3)}-m_2g=m_2a_2\\\Rightarrow a_2=-g\frac{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2-3m_3)}{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2+m_3)}$$
Having found $a_1$ and $a_2$, we can evaluate $a_3$ using equation $(4)$ as follows
$$a_3=-(2a_1+a_2)=-g\frac{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_3-3m_2)}{4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2+m_3)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one question: when working your way towards $a_1$, how did you do the last step? To get $a_1$. How did you eliminate the other $a_1$ factor?

Comment: I moved all the factors of $a_1$ to the left hand side, so I moved the $-4m_2m_3$ factor from the right hand side, changing sign. So we end up with $(4m_2m_3+m_1(m_2+m_3))a_1$

Comment: I'm not sure. We have $2T(m_2 + m_3) - 4m_2 m_3 g = -4a_1 (m_2 m_3)$. That's what you had too. Then we substitude for $2T$. We get $m_1 (a_1 + g) (m_2 + m_3) - 4m_2 m_3 g = -4a_1 (m_2 m_3)$. If I now move the $-4(m_2 m_3)$ factor to the left, we have $\frac{m_1 (a_1 + g) (m_2 + m_3)}{-4(m_2 m_3)} - \frac{4m_2 m_3 g}{-4(m_2 m_3)} = a_1$. Still there's a factor of $a_1$ on the left hand side, you know what I mean?

Comment: Rather than dividing both sides by $-4(m_2m_3)$, it will be easier to add both sides with $+4(m_2m_3)a_1$, so you can combine all the factors of $a_1$ together.